# 'Log as' with devise gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise

So in my ruby app I'm using devise and I'd like to have for the admins the ability to log as another user to assist them when they call for support.
But I've no idea how I should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what u are trying to do is to impersonate another user. i havent used this but u can check it out https://github.com/engineyard/user_impersonate

Comment: Just as a note they stopped supporting this. There is a fork at https://github.com/rcook/user_impersonate2

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the [Pretender](https://github.com/ankane/pretender) gem.

Pretender is flexible and lightweight - less than 60 lines of code.

Works with many authentication systems including `Devise`, `Authlogic`, and `Sorcery`.

Comment: Nice, I actually ended up using this gem

Comment: one problem with that gem is the impersonator and impersonating user needs to be the same class. What about if I want to impersonate User when I'm logged in as Admin ?

Answer (score 0):

[devise_masquerade](https://github.com/oivoodoo/devise_masquerade) is well worth a look if you're using Devise.

It does everything you might expect and is quite customizable. It even handles having [different model classes for users and admins](https://github.com/oivoodoo/devise_masquerade#you-can-redefine-few-options) (e.g. `User` and `AdminUser`).